# How can this MOSFET become overheated? How big should the heatsink be?

Tags: mosfet, heat, heatsink, watts

I've got a very simple circuit. A MOSFET ([TK15D60U](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1504734.pdf)) is powering a 3 to 4 Ohm heat bed by 19.6 volts. From my calculations this results in 6.5Amps. The power adapter seams to have its specs at max 6.32A but seems to function fine. The MOSFET should be able to handle 15Amps continous drain. The drain should be able to handle 600v, so that 19.6Vdc should be fine.

The gate is driven by a 25Vdc via a 10k resistor to the gate and 100k resistor from the gate to ground (to allow to leak away to discharge the gate, I thought it was a good thing). So effectively there is (25vdc/110k)*100k=22.7Vdc voltage at the gate. The Gate-source voltage is 30v so that is below max.

What I can read from the datasheet is that the Drain-source ON resistance @Vgs 10Vdc @ 10Amps is about 0.15Ohm. Lets take 0.2. I never really thought about the ON resistance. I thought, the gate would be fully open, so resistance should be minimum and will handle it without a problem. But when the MOSFET is active, it becomes too hot to touch within 10 seconds or so.

Now this part is something I am not so familiar with. Hence the question. Is it true that the formula P=(I2)*R (Watt=Ampere squared * resistance) yields (6.5A*6.5A)*0.2Ohm=6.5Watt that is dissipated via the MOSFET?

6.5Watt is a lot if you ask me on a TO-220. Is it not? How large should the heatsink be to handle that? Should I actively cool it using a fan? All I have now is this very tiny heatsink. This topic is probably a laugh for the experts around here.

[image: TO-220 heatsink]

Comment: 3/4 you mean 0.75 or 3R to 4R?

Comment: Are you using PWM? 10k gate resistor will give veeery slow turning on, therefore a lot of time on high Rds zone.

Comment: That is a really high RdsOn value. Pick another device with something much less than 0.1R

Comment: @BrianDrummond Sorry for the confusion, I meant 3 to 4 Ohm.

Comment: Way cool that stackexchange adds a link to the datasheet automatically! The datasheet from Farnell (that SE added) states with a BIG watermark: Not recommended for new design. The one I have doesn't state that. I see now, a RsdOn of 0.02Ohm is more common (obtained from a quick search)?

Comment: So that 4 to 6.5 Watts that the MOSFET will dissipate is correctly calculated?

Comment: It was not SE that added the link.. it was me ;)

Comment: @Trevor Correction: Way cool that SE members are so helpful in adding a link to the datasheet! Thanks Trevor.

Comment: YEs your math is pretty close... you need to factor in the on resistance with the load resistance to get the actual current though with one that big an on resistance.

Comment: @WesleyLee I have not verified but I think it is highly unlikely in this setup that it would be PWM. Thanks for your remark. Has it will only turn every 30 seconds or so I thought 10k would be a safe value.

Comment: @Trevor Yes I get your point of adding the resistance to get the total resistance. Which seems like an iterative calculation. However, the multimeter I have fluctuates on the Ohm measurement of the heat bed from 3 to 4 Ohm. So it is not accurate anyway. Thanks for the help. I will find another IC with much lower RdsOn.

Comment: Btw I calculate 7.5W worst case with Rload =3 and Ron = .2 I = 6.125. That squared *.2 =7.5W. And yes that is way too high for a bare To220.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I calculate 7.5W worst case with Rload =3 and Ron = .2

I = 6.125A.

That squared *.2R = 7.5W.

Yes that is way too high for a bare To220. At 83.3C/W channel to ambient of the device that's a whopping 625C temperature rise.. So it is going to melt.

You could add a whopping heat sink, but really, you need to find a different MOSFET that has an on resistance in the milliohm range.

Comment: I never thought about the C/W value. Thanks for adding that calculation. I understand more now how to pick a heatsink. I guess it comes down to taking my time to answer every question I have instead of 'rushing' to the information that I *think* I need. But thats with every thing when learning I guess.